# Does the body recieved from request module hold computed css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, node-request

I have following code and I want to download entire HTML with their respective computed CSS and convert it into JSON. I am trying request module.

```
request('http://www.modulus.io', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body); // Show the HTML for the Modulus homepage.
    }
});
```

Will the body just have the html or will it have everything? And how do I get the required css.

Comment: `body` will have the entire page ... how to get css, if it's not "inline", you parse the HTML in `body` variable and find external css references ... then parse those files for any included css files and/or images ...

Answer (score 1):

Getting the computed styles without rendering is not possible by my knowledge. So you could take a look at Phantom js or Selenium to render the page headless on a server. Or you take a look if the information you get from this stylestat is good enough https://github.com/t32k/stylestats.

As a third option you could download the page using request, finding the stylesheet reference using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio then downloading those files again and parse it using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssparser.

Third option example:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var cssparser = require("cssparser");
var cssbeautifier = require('cssbeautifier');
var parser = new cssparser.Parser();
var $;

request('http://www.modulus.io', function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Load into cheerio so we can work with it
        // as we would with jQuery
        $ = cheerio.load(body);

        var stylesheet = $('link[type="text/css"]').attr('href');

        request('http://www.modulus.io' + stylesheet, function(error, response, body){

            var css = cssbeautifier(body);
            var json = parser.parse( css );

           console.log('Your json ===>>', json);

        });


    }

});
```

But since this page is using some unknown character in there stylesheet this script error's so you will need to find a way around that.

Hope it helps, good luck!